# Working Backwards from Pressure Field to Transducer

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics

I am considering the problem of a pressure field generated by acoustic waves.  If I know the specific pressure field which I wish to generate, is it possible to work back to a transducer (or array of transducers) which I know would produce this pressure field?

Is this an example of an inverse problem?  If so, does it have to be solved numerically?